# Castle Windsor problem

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a problem with castle core, i'm trying to inject two different database connection to specific repositories.

```
public class Repository1 { 
  public Repository1(System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn) { } 
}
public class Repository2 { 
  public Repository2(System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn) { } 
}
```

Now for example im would like to inject Mysql connection to Repository1 and Oracle connection to repository2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<DbConnection>()
    .ImplementedBy<MysqlConnection>()
    .Named("mysql"));
container.Register(Component
    .For<DbConnection>()
    .ImplementedBy<OracleConnection>()
    .Named("oracle"));

container.Register(Component
    .For<Repository1>()
    .ServiceOverrides(new { conn = "mysql" }));
container.Register(Component
    .For<Repository2>()
    .ServiceOverrides(new { conn = "oracle" }));
```

You may need to tweak the DbConnection registrations, since I don't know what the exact class names might be, or whether they require other configuration settings.

Comment: what should i do when connection have the same type (i.e. mysqlconnection) but they different by configuration (connectionString). in this case windsor inject first declared connection.

Comment: Use the DependsOn method to supply a different connection string to each one of them.

Comment: Do i have to register connection string in container?

Comment: No, use the `DependsOn` method and supply it via that.

Comment: No, something like this: `DependsOn( new { conn = "myconnectionstring" })` You know, it's not so easy to post code here in the comments, so you might want to consider asking a *new* question.

Comment: @k1 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2856/discussion-between-mark-seemann-and-k1)